# i want to run my jmeter web driver script for 100 user without open browser

Tags: selenium, jmeter

when i was run jmeter webdriver script multiple browser is open and this condition not get accurate load testing report so how i get proper load testing report without open Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [WebDriver Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So you should not be using WebDriver Samplers to create the main load as browsers are very resource intensive and most probably you won't be able to kick off more than 5-10 browsers on a single machine.

If your requirement is to conduct the load testing using 100 real browsers - you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

If you want to use existing Selenium tests as a basis for a protocol-based load test you should record them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). You can set the proxy for your WebDriver tests as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So we have an option to run webdriver smaplers without opening the browsers if you are using chrome browser for this. You add **jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config** config element and there are 3 tabs in that those are "proxy", "chrome" and "Experimental". So you click on "chrome" tab and check the check box of **Use Chrome headless mode**. See the screenshot below.
[image]

In reality if you want to run webdriver samplers for more than 100 browser then I would suggest you that u use distributed test. Because browsers are resource consuming if you run around 4 browsers then your system starts hanging. so you cannot run 100 browsers. So go with Distributed testing in jmeter.